# How to access the uploaded image in HttpRequest in Flutter Android app?

Tags: javascript, html, dart, httpserver

I have been looking many resources for this but I couldn't find an answer so I hope someone could help me out please.

I am building a proof of concept of a Flutter Android app that does the following:

1. Runs an HTTP Web server that serves a simple html which allows image upload.
2. Saving the uploaded image in the app.
3. Be able to view the saved image in the app.

This html upload image site is accessible via browser.
In my case, I have been testing it using my desktop browser.

This is the html code:

```
    <form method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div>
            <label>Choose images to upload (PNG, JPG)</label>
            <input type="file" value="Upload File" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button>Submit</button>
          </div>
    </form>
```

In my app, I have this code:

```
HttpServer.bind('191.168.1.120', 3000).then((server) {
      server.listen((HttpRequest body) async {
        switch (body.requestedUri.path) {
            case '/upload':
             {
                //Question: How do I access the image from the body
                //Bonus Question: How do I save and store it in the app?
                body.response.statusCode = 201;
                body.response.close();
             }
             break;
            default:
             {
                String _content =
                  await rootBundle.loadString('assets/notfound.html');

                body.response.statusCode = 404;
                body.response.headers
                  .set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
                body.response.write(_content);
                body.response.close();
             }
        }
      }
}
```

If someone could pinpoint me on what to do at the "/upload" case, I will appreciate it very much.

PS: The bonus question is probably for a different thread but if it could be answered as well. It's greatly appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Comment: the question is not related to flutter

Comment: Hi Javeed, I see what you meant. The reason I put it as Flutter in the subject because this is a Flutter Android app.
And this app has this HttpServer code that's part of dart and it's true that it's not related to Flutter. I will correct the subject. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved using shelf package.
Here's my stackoverflow question where I asked using shelf package and the question was correctly answered:

[How to save image correctly that's being uploaded to Flutter Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68029065/how-to-save-image-correctly-thats-being-uploaded-to-flutter-android-app)

But if you're still interested using HttpRequest, please refer to this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hSkD3y9HMro